# How to link ssh key to ssh agent and push files to github account

Tags: github, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I need help on how to link my ssh key to ssh agent.

On generating the key which was saved at (mykeys) which i can view, the codes belows where generated in the bash terminal window.

```sh
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa): mykeys
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in mykeys
Your public key has been saved in mykeys.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:/DEK8rKIlb+j1aEVWL3jYG5I0dcuYk4DoKuxrHiGOws user@OshimiriAtata1
```

The error I keep getting for all my trials is:

```
No such file or directory
```

I have followed the instructions I get on various YouTube videos I am watching currently, but cannot figure out what the issue is.

I have tried the following:

```sh
ssh-add \~/.ssh/id_1895
ssh-add ..ssh/id_1895`your text`
ssh-add .ssh\\id_1895
ssh-add \~/.ssh/id_rsa`your text`
ssh-add \~/.Henry/.Data-set/.ssh_mykeys
```

All to no avail.
Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Following "[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the `ssh-agent`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)", the command would be:

```
sh-add C:\path\to\mykeys
```

And you would need a `~/.ssh/config` file with

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile C:\path\to\mykeys
```

Test if this works with: `ssh -Tv gh`, you should see a welcome message similar to:

```
Hi *****! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

You can use the URL with commands like:

```
git clone gh:myGitHubUser/myRepository
```

Comment: Thank you sir Vonc for your response but I am still unable to do it. I dont know what else to do. I will i could give you a call via Whatsapp for easier guide when you are less busy

Comment: @OshimiriJasper Sorry for not replying earlier. What error message do you see?

Comment: Yes Sir, I get the same "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: @OshimiriJasper What command do you type, which triggers the "`No such file or directory`" error message?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem, it kept putting the file on my desktop. I discovered this when I went to search on the bottom left of my Windows machine and typed in the name of my file, in your case "mykeys".

Literally followed the same exact steps you did and it still put it on my desktop.